# Check My Work: Chain Rule doesn't work when differentiating $x^{\ln(x)}$ ??

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, logarithms, chain-rule

I am asked to find the derivative of

> $$
> f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R},~x \mapsto x^{\ln(x)}
> $$

I am aware that I can rewrite it as $f(x) = e^{\ln^2(x)}$, and easily differentiate but I wanted to use the chain rule on the original function.
Here's my work:

The chain rule states
$$
\frac{d}{dx}~g(h(x)) = g'(h(x))\cdot h'(x)
$$
In this example, the 'outer' function is $g(x) := x^x$ with $g'(x) = x^x (\log(x) + 1)$ and the 'inner' function is $h(x) := \ln(x)$ with $h'(x) = x^{-1}$.

Appling the chain rule from above, I obtain

> $$
> f'(x) = \ln(x) ^{\ln(x)}~(\ln(\ln(x) + 1 )~\frac{1}{x}
> $$

When I let WolframAlpha plot this, I recognised my solution to be vastly different from the proposed solution
$$
f'(x) = \frac{2}{x}~\ln(x)~x^{\ln(x)}
$$
Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Well, you calculated the derivative of $g(h(x))=\ln x^{\ln x}$

Comment: Why are you differentiating $(\ln x)^{\ln x}$?

Comment: $g(h(x)) = (\ln(x))^{\ln(x)}$ and not $x^{\ln(x)}$

Comment: I think you would need to introduce a two-variable function $g(x,y)=x^y$. Then $\frac{d}{dx}x^{\ln x}=\frac{d}{dx}g(x,h(x))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,h(x))+h'(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,h(x))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already saw your mistake as pointed in the comments and in @gimusi's answer. A different approach (and one I find useful) is to take take $\log$ of your exponential function:

Let $y=\log(x^{\log(x)})=\log^2(x)$ and note that $e^y=x^{\log(x)}$. Then you have that

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2\log(x)}{x}$$

Hence you have that $$\frac{d(x^{\log(x)})}{dx}=\frac{d(e^y)}{dx}=e^y\frac{dy}{dx}=x^{\log(x)}\frac{2\log(x)}{x}$$

which is the answer you want

Answer (score 3):

Your method is wrong since with

- $g(x)=x^x$
- $h(x)=\log x$

we have that

$$g(h(x))=(\log x)^{\log x}\neq x^{\log x}$$